# catch last foreach item on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have listener here from postgre when anything changes on my db,
and it returning every row that i changed at the same time, how can i get the last item or run once only in nodejs

here is the example code of listener

```
//Listener from Postgre
pgsql_connection.query('LISTEN "whatsapp_listener"');
pgsql_connection.on("notification", function (data) {

    console.log("data", JSON.parse(data.payload));
    console.log('notif from database!'); 


});
```

Comment: Try calculating the length of your response and then access the last index by subtracting length by 1.

Comment: it worked now from ur suggestion , but i do have more issue psql db.on("notification") doesn't have a total index response so i have to make a dynamic index out of it

Comment: If possible, share your response so we can look further into it.